# nginx reverse proxy folder 403 error

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, reverse

I am running nginx as reverse proxy directly installed on the server. To access different webapps I am using sub folders. Two webapps are running in docker containers (pydio and cops).

For pydio this location commands are working; same one for cops is not working.

```
   location ^~ /pydio {
    client_max_body_size 20G;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I tried different settings found by searching - none worked.

This is the latest version which results in a 403 error:

```
   location ^~ /ebooks(.*)$ {
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
    rewrite ^/ebooks(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.100.67:83$1/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    autoindex on;
}
```

And this entry in my error.log:

> [error] 29235#29235: *1 directory index of "/var/www/ebooks/" is forbidden, client: 87.174.111.111, server: myadress.de, request: "GET /ebooks/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myadress.de"

When I hit *192.168.100.67:83* directly in my browser everything is working fine.

The folder /var/www/ebooks has www-data:www-data and 750 rights and it is linked with the container by the running command:

`docker run ... -v /var/www/ebooks:/config`  ... according to this https://hub.docker.com/r/lsioarmhf/cops/

Hope I made my problem clear and you will help me. Thanks

---

good an bad news.

After testing a little more I found setting passing the command to docker correctly.

```
    location ^~ /ebooks {

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        send_timeout 300;
        rewrite ^/ebooks(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83$1;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But cops page is only displayed in a basic way (background color changes but matrix not shown)

This is error log entry:

> an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/proxy/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: 11.114.211.38, server: myadress.de, request:: "GET /ebooks/resources/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1..js?v=1.0.1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:83/resources/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", host: "myadress.de", referrer: "https://myadress/ebooks/"

To give you a complete picture. This is nginx config of cops container.

```
    server {

    listen 80 default_server;
#   listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;
#   ssl_certificate /config/keys/cert.crt;
#   ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/cert.key;
    access_log  /config/log/nginx/access_cops.log;
    error_log /config/log/nginx/error_cops.log;
    root   /var/www/localhost/cops;
    index index.php;

    #Useful only for Kobo reader
    location /cops/ {
          rewrite ^/download/(\d+)/(\d+)/.*\.(.*)$ /fetch.php?data=$1&db=$2&type=$3 last;
          rewrite ^/download/(\d+)/.*\.(.*)$ /fetch.php?data=$1&type=$2 last;
          break;
        }

        #Can break loading the images - if you don't see anything, comment
        location ~ ^/images.*\.(gif|png|ico|jpg)$ {
                expires 31d;
        }
        #Can also break loading the images, comment if it happens
        location ~ .(js|css|eot|svg|woff|ttf)$ {
                expires 31d;
        }

    #Not necessarily correct, it depends on distro.
    location ~ \.php$ {
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
location /books {
      root /;
       internal;
}
}
```

Any ideas if I am missing something?

Comment: Is nginx running in a container?

Comment: No, nginx is installed "normal" on the server.